# How to repeat the animation using CATransition?

Tags: iphone, animation

I am using CATranition to animate a UIView. It animates properly, but I want this animation to continue until the view get unload.

I know I can use timer but want to know if there is some suitable way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

A `CATransition` is a `CAAnimation`, and so the documentation on [Repeating Animations](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/Timing.html) covers your issue.